# Vector push_backs done in multiple threads (within 20 sec) don't show correct vector size after wait_until(20 sec) in first thread

Tags: c++, multithreading, vector, wait

Based on the boost chat example and the wait_until example I'm trying to implement
adding messages to a vector (shared object) when a constructor is called
and the size of the vector should be given after a wait of 20 seconds.

What happens below when 2 CreateBlock calls happen within 20 seconds,
is that the first call of CreateBlock waits 20 seconds and then the size of the vector is 1,
then there's another wait for 20 seconds, also with vector size of 1.

CreateBlock call on the server, called asynchronously from 2 different clients:

```
CreateBlock cb(message_j);
```

The class:

```
#include <condition_variable>
#include <thread>
#include <chrono>
#include <vector>
#include "json.hpp"

class CreateBlock
{
public:
    CreateBlock(nlohmann::json &message_j)
    {
        std::thread th (&CreateBlock::waits, this, std::ref(message_j));
        th.join();
    }
private:
    void waits(nlohmann::json &message_j)
    {
        {
            std::lock_guard<std::mutex> guard(cv_m);
            message_j_vec_.push_back(message_j);
            std::cout << "message_j_vec_.size(): " << message_j_vec_.size() << std::endl; // = 1
        }

        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lk(cv_m);
        if(cv.wait_for(lk, 20s, [=]{return i == 1;})) 
        {
            std::cerr << "Thread finished waiting. i == " << i << '\n';
        }
        else
        {
            std::cerr << "Thread timed out. i == " << i << '\n';
            
            std::cout << "message_j_vec_.size(): " << message_j_vec_.size() << std::endl; // = 1
        }
    }
private:
    std::vector<nlohmann::json> message_j_vec_;

    std::condition_variable cv;
    std::mutex cv_m;
    int i;
};
```

I did try to make the vector static, put the vector in a separate class,
did CreateBlock* cb = new CreateBlock(message_j), tried to put the push_back in the constructor and the thread creation in another method, ...
but none of those experiments lead to the wished result.

Any idea on how to correctly solve this issue?

Tia.

Comment: The constructor does not return until the thread it created has terminated.

Comment: creating a thread and immediately joining it is rarely the right thing to do.

Comment: Is putting the vector push_back in the constructor and the thread creation in another method a solution?

Answer (score 0):

Well there was not really a response in here, so I knew I had to look differently at the problem than I showed here. And so I looked into a previous step of the code and worked then towards a solution with a static variable.
I finally succeeded into getting a correct size in the place where I wanted it.

Thanks for pointing me into the right direction by remaining silent! Not the conventional way, but it worked. Took me a good week though!!